# Other people's files showing up in rhythmbox

Tags: networking, rhythmbox

I have my computer connected to a *college network*, and right now files that belong to other individuals on campus are showing up under Shared in rhythmbox. This is driving me up the wall, I absolutely despise the idea that files are being thrown around on the network and that other people's s*** is showing up on my computer, and that they may be able to see my files as well.

This is a very, very serious problem as far as I am concerned and I want to know how I can ensure that I am sharing nothing with the network in the way of files on my computer and that no one else's files are showing up on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox has the ability to pick up files from several locations - both locally and "sniffing" out network locations.

If you look in your Rhythmbox plugins you have a plugin called DAAP - a protocol to look for a DAAP server.  It is likely your college friends are using such a server to distribute music.

[image: pic] - untick the option shown to not use DAAP.

If you also look further down the list you have the *MediaServer2 D-Bus Interface* and the *MRPIS D-Bus Interface*.  Again, uncheck those if you are not using those interfaces to find music.

Using `dconf-editor` available if you install the `dconf-tools` package, you also have some likely candidate keys you can uncheck as well to further restrict sharing:

[image: pic] - navigate org -> gnome -> rhythmbox -> sharing in the tree view and uncheck both enable-browsing and enable-sharing